# resetting a set interval for slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, setinterval

I'm just beginning in Jquery and learning pretty quickly, but I spent the past few hours trying to figure out how to reset an interval, if someone could please explain this concept to me it would help me out a lot. I have an interval firing a click that changes the image every 6s. I would like to be able to reset that interval again at 6s every time that click is fired, so that when a user clicks to advance the slideshow the next image will wait 6 seconds before appearing. thanks!

```
<html><head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    /*Home Header Slideshow*/
    #headercontainer {width:700px; height:300px; margin-left:-10px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
    #nextslide {position:absolute; top:257; left:553; z-index:100; width:47px; height:43px; background:url(images/slidearrow.png)}
    #nextslide:hover {background-position: 0 43px;}
    #gallery{width: 600px; height:300px; position:absolute; left:0px;}
        #gallery a{width:600px; height:300px; position:absolute;}
        .shownslide{display:block; z-index:100;}
        #i1{background:url("images/slideimage1.jpg");}
        #i2{background:url("images/slideimage2.jpg");}
        #i3{background:url("images/slideimage3.jpg");}
        #i4{background:url("images/slideimage4.jpg");}          
    #thumbs{width:100px; height:300px; position:absolute; right:0px;}
        #thumbs a{display:block; width:100px; height:100px; position:relative;}
        #t1{background:url("images/slidethumb1.jpg");}
        #t2{background:url("images/slidethumb2.jpg");}
        #t3{background:url("images/slidethumb3.jpg");}
        #t4{background:url("images/slidethumb4.jpg");}
</style>
</head>
<center>
<div id="headercontainer">
            <a id="nextSlide" href="#"></a>
<div id="gallery">
            <a id="i4" href="#"></a>
            <a id="i3" href="#"></a>
            <a id="i2" href="#"></a>
            <a id="i1" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div id="thumbs">
    <a id="t2" href="#"></a>
            <a id="t3" href="#"></a>
    <a id="t4" href="#"></a>
            <a id="t1" href="#"></a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script>
var slideDelay = 6000;

$(function(){
    $('#nextSlide').bind('click',nextSlide);
    $('#nextSlide').trigger('click');
    setInterval(nextSlide,slideDelay);
});

function nextSlide(){
    $('#gallery a:last').stop(true, true);
    $('#thumbs a:first').stop(true, true);
    $('#gallery a:last').fadeOut(function() {$(this).remove();});
    $('#gallery a:last').clone().prependTo('#gallery');
    $('#thumbs a:first').slideUp(function() {$(this).remove();});
    $('#thumbs a:first').clone().appendTo('#thumbs');
};

 </script>
 </center>

     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clear an interval if you assign it to a variable using

```
window.clearInterval(intervalID)
```

and to assign an interval you would use,

```
var intervalID = setInterval(func, 6000);
```

In your case you could either overwrite the interval when they click, which in effect will reset the interval, or you can use `clearInterval` and then reset it.

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval)**

**EDIT**

In your case, from your comment I would just use `setTimeout` instead `setInterval`. Its only fired once, but if you put it in nextslide, it will get cleared if its already set, and then reset every time regardless of how the `nextSlide()` function is called.

```
var timeout = '';

function nextSlide(){
    $('#gallery a:last').stop(true, true);
    $('#thumbs a:first').stop(true, true);
    $('#gallery a:last').fadeOut(function() {$(this).remove();});
    $('#gallery a:last').clone().prependTo('#gallery');
    $('#thumbs a:first').slideUp(function() {$(this).remove();});
    $('#thumbs a:first').clone().appendTo('#thumbs');

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){nextSlide()}, slideDelay);
};
```

Comment: okay yes, I understand how to use both of those setInterval and clearInterval. The problem I am having is the process of how I would reset the interval on the click.